# Getting single dimensional array, not multi dimensional

Tags: coffeescript

When I run

```
[w*2 for w in [1, 2, 3]]
```

I get

```
[[2, 4, 6]]
```

but actually I want

```
[2, 4, 6]
```

[Live example](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aconsole.log%20%5Bw%2a2%20for%20w%20in%20%5B1,%202,%203%5D%5D%0A)

Obviously following is in option, but I do not want to rely on that:

```
[w*2 for w in [1, 2, 3]][0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself:

```
(w*2 for w in [1, 2, 3])
// -> [2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: Because of coffeescript's "everything returns a value" ideal, the `[]` are not necessary to make it behave like a list comprehension.  The `()` are usually, but not always, necessary, depending on what you're trying to do with the result and what whitespace you're using.

Comment: @AaronDufour: Thank you for your input. In my case the brackets are necessary, don´t you think?

Comment: They're not; see http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#try:w*2%20for%20w%20in%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D  However, ifyou want to assign the result like `a = (w*2 for w in [1, 2, 3])`, they are necessary; otherwise the `a = w*2` will be the body of the loop rather than just `w*2`.